# django login not redirecting to index

Tags: python, django, authentication

I have got a login screen, which upon successful authentication should show user details on the same base URL , it used to work just fine all these days, and all of a sudden it's throwing 302 response code `HTTP POST /login/ 302 [0.60, 127.0.0.1:53864]` when the correct username and password is entered, no redirection is initiated, it forever keeps loading.
What's more strange is that when I reload the same tab or open a new tab, it is correctly logged in and shows the appropriate details. No changes related to login functionality were made, the only recent change I made was to add **reset password** functionality which had nothing to do with this.

**user_login**

```
def user_login(request):

    field = None

    if request.method == "POST":
        
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)

        try:

            field = UserModel.objects.get(user__username=username)

            if user:
           
                if user.is_active:
                    
                    login(request,user)
                    
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
                else:
                    messages.error(request,'username or password not correct')
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('../')
            else:
                print("Error logging in{}".format(password))
                messages.error(request,'Invalid username/password combination')
                return HttpResponseRedirect('../')
        
        except Exception:
            #return HttpResponse("ACCOUNT NOT ACTIVE!!!")
            messages.error(request,'Entered username does not belong to any account')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('../')
  
    else:
        return render(request,'app/login.html',{})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$',views.IndexView.as_view(),name='index'),
    url(r'login/',views.user_login,name='login'),]
```

**AIM: To show login and user details(logged in view) on the same base URL(127.0.0.1:8000), i.e if a user is logged in, show user details, else show login form**
**IndexView**

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'app/index.html'

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            today = date.today()
            print(today)
            context['products'] =ProductModel.objects.filter(usr=self.request.user)
           
            
            print("LOGGED IN")
          
            return context
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends 'app/base.html' %}

{%block title %}
<title>TITLE</title>
{% endblock %}


{%block body %}

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  {% include 'app/header.html' %}
<div class="container">

  
  <h1>Welcome {{user.username}}</h1>
 
    {% else %}
<!--LOGIN FORM HERE-->
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

It was working without any problems all these days, not sure of what's causing this. Please suggest fixes for this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: There is redirection initiated. After login you are redirecting the user to reverse('index') using `HttpResponseRedirect` and that class returns a 302 response. There's nothing wrong with the view though. You need to check what your IndexView is doing since that's where you're redirecting the user

Comment: Does after loading for many seconds, the browser gives a too many redirects error?

Comment: No such error is shown, however when I manually reload(ctrl+R), it renders the appropriate details.

Comment: This problem occurs when I open the browser for the first time after closing it(on subsequent logins and logouts, it somehow redirects but still the 302 response code comes up)

Comment: I just observed that this problem occurs not only while login, but during logout also. Since this has got something to do with authentication and redirection, is this any common problem or does it have any fixes?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so this is a weird one but I saw it in production for one of my apps and I **think** it's to do with the browsers' caching. It's been really hard to reproduce reliably but since I put the following fix out (for something actually unrelated) the problem seems to have been fixed.

Try setting `cache-control` for the response:

```py
response = HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
response['cache-control'] = 'private, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store'
return response
```

Please tell me if this works, it's been bugging me that I haven't found out if my fix has actually worked!

To add middleware, [as per Django's docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/middleware/):

**middleware.py**

```py
class CacheControlMiddleware(SimpleMiddleware):
    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

        response = self.get_response(request)
        response['cache-control'] = 'private, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store'
        return response
```

Then in settings.py, add:

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'my_app.middeware.CacheControlMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: Tried, the problem still persists. Also tried in incognito mode, yet the same problem. What's more strange is, when I reload after entering the correct credentials, it logs in, further upon logging out and again logging in I still get a 302 response code but it redirects to the desired screen without having to reload.

Comment: This is annoying, I'm afraid I don't know then. I also see the request coming in and the 302 response, but the browser hangs. Are you seeing this every time? Have you tried different browsers?

Comment: I have only tried on chrome(regular and incognito mode). Happens when I open the browser for the first time(on subsequent logins and logouts, it somehow redirects but still the 302 response code comes up).

Comment: Try setting that `cache-control` header in middleware, I can confirm that since I changed that, neither myself nor my colleagues have had the issue.

Comment: Does that require me to install any third-party package? Could you please guide me to add it to middleware?

Comment: Nope, that didn't work as well. Still causing the same problem.

Comment: Hey @PrajwalKulkarni, did you ever manage to get to the bottom of this? It's an issue I'm seeing a lot now, would be great to know where you go to before I go digging! Thanks so much